# Constructor undefined, says Eclipse, but its defined (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't get it, why is this constructor not defined. I check some other similar questions here, but there was always the problem, that they wanted to call the constructor without parameters, while the constructor had parameters. But I don't see this problem in my code. Could you please help me? Thank you!

I get the error message: `The constructor Node(int) is undefined`

---

**The class with the main method:**

```
package LLP;

public class LinkedList2Test {

public void main (String args[]){
    LinkedList2 test = new LinkedList2();

    test.add(13);
    test.add(10);
    test.add(21);
}
}
```

---

**The LinkedList2 class**

```
package LLP;

public class LinkedList2 {

Node head;
Node tail;

public void add(int data){

    **Node node = new Node(data);**// **THE PROBLEM is here**

    if (tail == null){
        tail = node;
        head = node;
    } else {
        tail.nextNode = node;
        tail=node;
    }
}
}
```

---

**The Node class**

```
package LLP;

public class Node {
int data;
Node nextNode;

public Node (int data){
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

---

As I see, in the main method I give in an integer, for example '13'.
The add method receives this integer and calls it as 'data'
And I would like to create the node with that 'data'
Node's constructor needs just one integer, which would be 'data' so now 13 for example

Why does it not work, i dont get it...

Many Thanks

Comment: `**Node node = new Node(data);**` what're the double asterisks doing there?

Comment: just added for emphasis. although if those are there at compile time, i think we found the problem. lol

Comment: It _should_ be `public static void main(String args[])`, not `public void main(String args[])` first of all.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answers. 
@mypal - cheers, i corrected it, but it was not the problem
somehow the problem disappeared after a restart, a classical help desk solution, but I never experienced such a behavior by eclipse...
So save and restart... i was suffering with it like for one hour, cause i couldnt find the problem...
Thanks for you anyway!

Comment: and the ** I just added to it here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. I guess it could be that you didn't save your Node class after you provided a constructor hence the error.

Also as @mypal125 you probably want `static` main method in your `LinkedList2Test` class. After changing that try to run (running also automatically saves all the changes) your program and see if there is still an error.

Answer (score 5):

I had that problem a couple of times now with eclipse. What usually works is
selecting a line where the error is and a sequence of

ctrl+x

ctrl+v

Comment: What's the point in copying the line, when you cut it right after that?

Comment: It worked for me more than once.
I am guessing it is an Eclipse parsing problem...

Comment: In fact I had to use it today (that is how I got to this thread). And restarting Eclipse did not work. It looked really weird as well. After opening a project that I was working on for a couple of days the class that had a long list of static final object initializations for a list of constant objects and that worked before started acting up and some lines started showing constructor is not defined error. The procedure above solved it. I realize that it is definitely a hack, but it worked for me before, so I decided to share it.

Comment: It worked, because cutting and pasting the line triggers a recompiling, so you shouldn't need to copy that line. "ctrl+x" + "ctrl+v" should be enough.

Comment: Amazingly 7 years after, and the bug persists. Thanks for your answer, @IgorMedvedyev !

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedList2 class is missing the constructor.

Add this to your LinkedList2 class:

```
public LinkedList2(int data){ }
```

Comment: That's not the problem. He is not using a constructor like that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a glitch with Eclipse. For me it occurred following the renaming of the class being instantiated, and refactoring.

For me Ctrl-x Ctrl-v worked only temporarily.

What worked for me was closing the Editor tab of the class being instantiated. In fact closing all tabs in the Eclipse editor (and reopening those you need) seems to clear Eclipse's confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, the error “The constructor Node(int) is undefined” appeared after I right clicked on a folder and selected Build Path -> Use as Source Folder.  To fix this issue, I followed the following steps:

1. Rename the package containing the class(es) with the error
2. Create a new folder using the old folder (package) name
3. Create any preexisting subfolders under the folder just created
4. Move the old class(es) from the renamed package to its rightful place in the new folder structure
5. Once all the classes have been moved from the renamed package to the new folder structure, delete the package
6. Perform a Project -> Clean